# Firestore - Authenticate users in rules while using multiple projects and multiple authentications

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have multiple projects with multiple authentications. Authorized users from `Project A` and `Project B` access the database of `Project C`. In the database rules of `Project C`, I need to know where they came from (`Project A` or `Project B`) to write better rules for them.

For example, authorized users from `Project A` should not have the ability to delete documents while authorized users from `Project B` has that ability.

Comment: how did you solve the authentication? I am having troubles to sign up in project A but using the same credentials to be valid in Project C.

Answer (score 0):

I can use the [Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) mechanism. I give users from `Project A` and `Project B` different roles (i.e. `AAdmin` and `BAdmin`) using custom claims once they signed in. Then, I check their roles in Security Rules.